# Magento 2: How to Automatically Create Invoice from Order Observer

Tags: magento2, php, invoice

I'm testing on Magento 2.2.3 and I've created an observer for the event `sales_order_save_after` which I'm using to automatically create an invoice.

Here is the current error that I'm receiving after placing an order:

`Order saving error: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.`

And my `MyCompany/MyModule/Observer/SalesOrderSaveAfter.php`

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrderSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_invoiceService;
    protected $_transactionFactory;

    public function __construct(
      \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService,
      \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory
    ) {
       $this->_invoiceService = $invoiceService;
       $this->_transactionFactory = $transactionFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        try {
            if(!$order->canInvoice()) {
                return null;
            }
            if(!$order->getState() == 'new') {
                return null;
            }

            $invoice = $this->_invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order);
            $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
            $invoice->register();

            $transaction = $this->_transactionFactory->create()
              ->addObject($invoice)
              ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

            $transaction->save();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Exception message: '.$e->getMessage(), false);
            $order->save();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the transaction portion of the code, eg:

```
$transaction = $this->_transactionFactory->create()
    ->addObject($invoice)
    ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

    $transaction->save();
```

then the order will pass through with the products marked as invoiced, but no invoice is actually created or saved to the order.

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: The biggest problem is that your order hadn't yet been committed to the database and so your transaction results in a foreign key constraint error. (i.e. the sales_invoice table has an `order_id` column but your order hasn't yet been committed) Does this need to fired after all transactions or just those on the frontend?  If the latter, try using the `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

Comment: @Aj47, Yes Phil Birnie is right. You should use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` action to create invoice

Comment: @PhilBirnie ah that makes sense then, I actually need this to fire from orders placed from the admin as well.  I've also tried `sales_order_place_after` but ran into the same issue.  Is there an event that would work for admin orders?

Comment: looks like `checkout_submit_all_after` did the trick and I'll just move `events.xml` to `adminhtml` folder so it only fires from admin.  Is that the best event to use for this application?

Comment: I want to create an invoice and send mail when order shipped. Have you any idea about this?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh you can use the code above to create the Invoice, and then once order is shipped you can use the `sales_order_shipment_save_after` event to fire off an observer to send the email.  I would suggest creating a new question though.

Comment: Need to generate the invoice automatically once the shipment is created. M2EE any one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out, the answer to this is that I was using the wrong event. With the event `sales_order_save_after` the order hasn't been committed to the Database yet.

I changed my event to fire on `checkout_submit_all_after` and my observer is now working.

Comment: Do you understand why after the `sales_order_save_after` event the order hasn't been committed to the database?

Comment: @LucaS Unfortunately, I'm not 100% sure why this is the case -- I know in Magento 1.8.x+ I could use `sales_order_save_after` event to fire off an automatic invoice.  But not sure the difference in M2

Comment: i tried this in magento2.3 but it not work

Comment: @JigsParmar , just tested on our 2.3 store and seems to still be working.  You may have something else going on.  Feel free to post a separate question and I can take a look!

Comment: its working now , i trying to generate shipping programatically thats the issue

Comment: Need to generate the invoice automatically once the shipment is created. M2EE any idea?

Comment: @YoYoRoshan You would likely use an event for shipment created, such as `sales_order_shipment_save_after`. And then in your observer you would get the order from the shipment and invoice it similar to above code in my original question.

Comment: @AJK Invoice is created but after redirected to the order view page I am getting this error --> adminhtml/session

Comment: I am not able to get this error (adminhtml/session) why it's coming on again and again after shipment .

Answer (score 4):

Automatically Create Invoice after place the order from Order Observer using event `checkout_submit_all_after`. Follow below file path to create custom module and makes auto invoice after place order.

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/AutoInvoice/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_AutoInvoice',
    __DIR__
);
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/AutoInvoice/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_AutoInvoice" setup_version="2.1.0" />
</config>
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/AutoInvoice/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="vendor_checkout_submit_all_after" instance="Vendor\AutoInvoice\Observer\OrderObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/AutoInvoice/Observer/OrderObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\AutoInvoice\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_invoiceCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_invoiceRepository;

    /**
    * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService
    */
    protected $_invoiceService;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory
     */
    protected $_transactionFactory;

    /**
    * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
    */
    protected $_orderRepository;

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory $invoiceCollectionFactory
    * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService
    * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory
    * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface $invoiceRepository
    * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory $invoiceCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface $invoiceRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
        ) {
          $this->_invoiceCollectionFactory = $invoiceCollectionFactory;
          $this->_invoiceService = $invoiceService;
          $this->_transactionFactory = $transactionFactory;
          $this->_invoiceRepository = $invoiceRepository;
          $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }




    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {   
        $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
        $this->createInvoice($orderId);      

    }

    protected function createInvoice($orderId)
    {
        try 
        {
            $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);
            if ($order)
            {
                $invoices = $this->_invoiceCollectionFactory->create()
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq' => $order->getId()));

                $invoices->getSelect()->limit(1);

                if ((int)$invoices->count() !== 0) {
                  $invoices = $invoices->getFirstItem();
                  $invoice = $this->_invoiceRepository->get($invoices->getId());
                  return $invoice;
                }

                if(!$order->canInvoice()) {
                    return null;
                }

                $invoice = $this->_invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order);
                $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
                $invoice->register();
                $invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(false);
                $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment(__('Automatically INVOICED'), false);
                $transactionSave = $this->_transactionFactory->create()->addObject($invoice)->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
                $transactionSave->save();

                return $invoice;
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __($e->getMessage())
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we have use same event and give error on place order {"message":"We can't save the address:\n\"Last name\" is required. Enter and try again.\n\"First Name\" is required. Enter and try again.","trace":"#0