# Prepaid order creation from magento 2 backend

Tags: magento2, admin, custom, payment-methods

I added a custom payment option for Magento 2 admin. When using the payment option checkout from admin the order total showing as the total due.
[image]

How to make it as total paid instead of Total Due when i am using my custom payment option placing an order from admin

**config.xml**

```
<default>
        <payment>
            <adminpaymentmethod>
                <active>1</active>
                <title>Pay Online</title>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <preselect>1</preselect>
                <model>Vendor\AdminPaymentMethod\Model\AdminPaymentMethod</model>
            </adminpaymentmethod>
        </payment>
    </default>
```

Comment: Do you create a custom payment?

Comment: I created a custom payment for admin. When admin using that payment means I need to make total should be paid instead of due.

Comment: Should try this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217045/magento-2-how-to-automatically-create-invoice-from-order-observer

Comment: Thanks for your reply I want to set the payment as paid when admin used to checkout order from the backend using a specific payment method.

Comment: you need just to create the invoice for your order and the amount will be set to paid, see my ansewer below

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an INVOICE and thats all.
When **you create the invoice Amount Due will become paid** (Your admin user has just to create the invoice once order is created, or you can create it [programatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217045/magento-2-how-to-automatically-create-invoice-from-order-observer) so he does not take that step)

NOTE : Why don't you just use ***check / money order*** method ? Do your custom method have specific logic?

Before invoice :
[image: just created, before invoice]

After invoice :
[image: invoice created, now amount is paid]

Comment: I didn't use cod because i having cod charges. I only go for custom payment method only when I received money from the customer and after that only I create an order for customers from the backend. I need to make it as prepaid before the invoice get generated.

Comment: you can create the invoice programatically then, but still cannot see why just don't create manually as you are already in admin panel

Comment: my requirement is, need to make it as a prepaid order before creating an invoice.

Comment: Even legally you have to invoice as you received a payment. And so functionally a paid order should be invoiced.

Comment: I want to change the method name as prepaid it is currently showing as COD